# Jump an HTML video according to time object in React or JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

I have a requirement where I need to play a html video with time jumps.

Scenario is like this:-

I have an array that contains time markers like this `const obj = [{start: 2.64, end: 5.79}, {start: 7.95, end: 8.69}]`.

The requirement is that the video should start from 2.64 and play till 5.79 and then jump to 7.95 and then end at 8.69 and so on.

My solution is like this:-

```js
const timers = this.state.timers;
let video = this.videoRef;
if (video) {
  let index = 0;
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    if (parseInt(video.currentTime) == parseInt(timers[timers.length - 1].end)) {
      video.pause()
    }
    if (timers[index]) {
      if (parseInt(video.currentTime) == parseInt(timers[index].end)) {
        if (index <= timers.length - 1) {
          index++;
          if (timers[index]) {
            video.currentTime = timers[index].start;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      tickTime: Math.ceil(video.currentTime)
    })
  })
  video.play().then(res => {
    video.currentTime = timers[0].start
  })
}
```

It is working fine but when the video currenttime is like 2.125455 and in time object has end time 2.95, the parseInt function make both the time 3 and the video jumps to 3, so the 8 ms never plays, these 8ms are also very critical in my case

any solution on this please?

I am stuck for a while now

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was able to resolve the problem

Thanks anyways

Here is the solution if anyone else facing it

```
const timers = this.state.timers;
let video = this.videoRef;
if (video) {
  let index = 0;
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    if (video.currentTime >= timers[timers.length - 1].end) {
      video.pause()
    }
    if (timers[index]) {
      if ((video.currentTime) >= (timers[index].end)) {
        if (index <= timers.length - 1) {
          index++;
          if (timers[index] && video.currentTime < timers[index].start) {
            video.currentTime = timers[index].start;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      tickTime: Math.ceil(video.currentTime)
    })
  })
  video.play().then(res => {
    video.currentTime = timers[0].start
  })
}
```